# Multi-output functional API keras model is returning columns in combined values

Tags: python, keras

I have a functional API model with 3 output layers but each output layer contains multiple columns for a total of 15 columns of output(predictions). But instead when I try to predict it is returning only 3 columns of output which I am guessing are a combined value of the columns for that output layer.

here is my code for my model:

```
    # Regression model #1 (Date)
    input1 = Input(shape=(50,3))
    date_reg_layer1 = LSTM(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0000001), 
                   activity_regularizer=l2(0.0000001))(input1)
    date_reg_layer2 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(date_reg_layer1)
    date_reg_layer3 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(date_reg_layer2)              
    
    # Regression model #2 (Location)
    input2 = Input(shape=(50,2))
    loc_reg_layer1 = LSTM(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0000001), 
                   activity_regularizer=l2(0.0000001))(input2)
    loc_reg_layer2 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(loc_reg_layer1)               
    loc_reg_layer3 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(loc_reg_layer2)
    
    # Classification model #3
    input3 = Input(shape=(50,10))
    class_layer1 = LSTM(64, activation='relu')(input3)
    class_layer2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(class_layer1)
    
    
    # Concatenate Layer
    concat_layer = Concatenate()([date_reg_layer3, loc_reg_layer3, class_layer2])
    
    # Final hidden Dense layer
    FullDense_layer = Dense(64, activation='relu')(concat_layer)
    
    # Output layers
    output_layer1 = Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')(FullDense_layer) #3 columns
    output_layer2 = Dense(2, activation = 'softmax')(FullDense_layer) #2 columns
    output_layer3 = Dense(10, activation = 'sigmoid')(FullDense_layer) #10 columns (one hot encoded classifier)
    
    # Put model together and compile it
    model = Model([input1, input2, input3], [output_layer1, output_layer2, output_layer3])

    opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, clipnorm=1.0, clipvalue=0.4)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=['mae','mse','binary_crossentropy'], metrics=['accuracy'])

    # train the model with the 3 inputs (total 15 columns) and 3 outputs(15 columns)
    history = model.fit([trainX[:,:,0:3], trainX[:,:,3:5], trainX[:,:,5:15]], [trainY[:,0:3], trainY[:,3:5],trainY[:,5:15]], epochs=5, batch_size=128, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1)

    # Predictions
    n_past = 16
    num_preds=20  #let us predict past 20 observations


    #Make prediction
    prediction = model.predict([trainX[-num_preds:,:,0:3], trainX[-num_preds:,:,3:5], trainX[-num_preds:,:,5:15]])
```

For the above model I am expecting 15 columns of output but only getting 3.  Can someone please help?

Comment: What do columns mean here? It is much better to describe the shape of the arrays you are receiving as output.

Comment: well i have 3 output layers defined first one is (20,3) second:  (20,2) and third (20,10) so total expecting is 15 columns and the 20 repersents the amount of predictions in the future. but instead I am getting back output in a shape of (20,3)

Comment: 20 should be the batch dimension, the number 3 represents the number of outputs, inside each element you get each of your outputs, the model will never predict (20,15), that is just not how multi-output models work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am still very confused.  I get that the my model is only producing 3 outputs but I need a prediction for each original column in my dataset.  Would I instead have to adjust my model to have 15 output layers?

Comment: Again with the columns, what does that even mean here? Since you are using LSTMs, I think you mean timesteps, not columns.

Comment: You need to consider that the input of your model is (samples, timesteps, features), so columns has no meaning here (it is not a 2D structure).

Comment: by columns I mean the # of features.  My original dataset has a shape of (10000, 15) and I want my predictions to be a total of (20, 15). (20 predictions into the future and 15 columns or features)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243621/discussion-between-samir112-and-dr-snoopy).

Answer (score 0):

I posed this question to find out how to access the different dimensions of the predictions because i was looking for 3 output arrays that total 15 features (i incorrectly referred to them as columns in the original question)

Here is how I did it which was a very simple solution.

```
prediction[0] #3 features
prediction[1] #2 features
prediction[2] #10 features
```